# Put a Subdomain on a Different Server Hosting

Tags: web-hosting, subdomain

I have a domain (www.mydomain.com) hosted on Hosting A. How can I have the subdomain (sub.mydomain.com) to be hosted on Hosting B?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is relatively easy to do.

Using example.com, you have:

An A record for the example.com
A CNAME (as an alias) pointing www to example.com (www is a sub-domain)
--where www = example.com
-- or --
An A record for www.example.com

To have sub-domain.example.com you would have:

An A record for sub-domain.example.com
--where the IP address is for the new host and the website domain is set-up as sub-domain.example.com within the new hosts control panel.

That should be it.